# Xamarin ViewModel Simplify Multiple Properties

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In a `ViewModel` I typically have lots of similar code blocks like the following:

```
    // Foo prop
    int _foo;
    public int Foo
    { 
        get { return _foo; }
        set 
        { 
            _foo = value;
            notifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Foo));
        } 
    }
```

Describing one single property. This one shows an integer, but I mostly have strings.

IMHO, this bloats up code pretty quickly.

Is there a neat way to simplify this? Maybe with a preprocessor macro?

Comment: https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged will eliminate the need for the boilerplate INPC code

Comment: I think everyone faces this problem sooner or later. We have to write every property mapped in the ViewModel, causing a lot of repetitive work. You may want to look for MFractor, which is a tool that allows you to automatically create properties in the ViewModel based on the data in the view, saving you time to write repetitive properties. You can find the complete documentation here: http://docs.mfractor.com/